# Haskell: issue with installing Yesod/Snap and I suppose any other package via cabal on Windows 7

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm new to Haskell and trying to install Snap (http://snapframework.com) on Windows 7. I have already installed GHCi and cabal. 
  Starting to do the same things as explained in the documentation on the site but I have the next exception:

cabal install snap

```
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading blaze-builder-0.3.3.2...
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
Failed to install blaze-builder-0.3.3.2
Downloading byteable-0.1.1...
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
Failed to install byteable-0.1.1
Downloading crypto-api-0.12.2.2...
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
Failed to install crypto-api-0.12.2.2
Downloading enumerator-0.4.20...
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
Failed to install enumerator-0.4.20
Downloading extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4...
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
Failed to install extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4
Downloading generic-deriving-1.6.2...
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
Failed to install generic-deriving-1.6.2
Downloading logict-0.6.0.1...
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
Failed to install logict-0.6.0.1
Downloading mwc-random-0.13.1.0...
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
Failed to install mwc-random-0.13.1.0
Downloading safe-0.3.3...
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
Failed to install safe-0.3.3
Downloading transformers-compat-0.1.1.1...
```

The same stuff happen with Yesod, so seems to be either cabal is not really good works on Windows 7 or some magic configuration needs to be applied before starting installing any package via cabal

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?  At first glance it looks like all internet traffic is being redirected to an HTML page, possibly requesting some sort of authentication, or terms of use....  Can you verify that regular internet browsing is working?

Comment: This definitely looks like a firewall or proxy issue, cabal does not download HTML files to my knowledge.

Comment: Often before installing a package for the first time, you should run `cabal update` to get the latest information from hackage. See if that helps.

Comment: Cabal will Just Work on W7 with the default network configurations. The 'workaround' is to just download the packages and install from disk.

Answer (score 0):

But even when I do

```
C:\Users\Bogdan>cabal update
```

have the same issue

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse
"parseResponseHead Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
cabal: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorParse "parseResponseHead
Response status line parse failure: <html>\r\n"
```

Of course I can do internet browsing. If it is firewall or proxy issue it's happening only for Haskell. Does it use some special configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, you may need to add the proxy settings as environment variables for `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` and not simply rely on the proxy autoconfiguration that works for your web-browser.